# CamelCase Issue In MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I just discovered an issue in my query where I match words that are CamelCased. I get the value from URI like this:

```
$county = $_GET['county'];
```

Then I pass it to my query and I noticed that only 'McMullen' or 'mcMullen' will work but anything else will fail. I tried to modify my query like this but nothing seems to work.

```
 WHERE LCASE(county) LIKE '%$county%'

 WHERE LCASE(county) LIKE '$county'

 WHERE LCASE(county) = '$county'

 WHERE LCASE(county) LIKE '%$county%'

 LOWER(CONVERT(county USING utf8mb4))  LIKE '$county'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try to force the URL value to lower case also (`$county = strtolower($_GET['county']);`)?

Comment: Are you sure that you're using a case sensitive collation?

Comment: Opefully, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html , will shed some light on the annoyance you are experiencing.

Comment: @Strawberry The table collation is set to latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: @Dave I have lower-cased both sides.

Comment: In that case, case comparisons are meaningless

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad, I think I figured it out. The evaluation happens elsewhere, not in the query, which works fine.

Comment: Just delete the question

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't allow me because of all responses.